# Como utilizar o ngFor com um dicionario em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular

Estou tentando gerar uma página dinâmica com Angular 9, minha ideia é a cada chave do dicionário
criar um tag optgoup e a cada valor um option, mas não estou conseguindo acessar os valores do objeto dict.

Código:

```
  <optgroup *ngFor="let categoria in categorias" [label]="categoria">
    <option *ngFor="let valor in categorias[categoria]" >{{ valor }}</option>
  </optgroup>
```

Exemplo:

```
// Dict
var categorias = {
  "Pediatra": ["Igor", "Luiz", "Ricardo"],
  "Ortopedista ": ["João", "Lucas", "Julia"]
};
```

Resultado:

```
<optgroup label="Pediatra">
   <option>Igor</option>
   <option>Luiz</option>
   <option>Ricardo</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Ortopedista">
   <option>João</option>
   <option>Lucas</option>
   <option>Julia</option>
</optgroup>
```

Comment: Ocorre algum erro ou simplesmente não sai como esperado?

Comment: Não ocorria erro, o Angular gerava a build e aparecia a tag optgroup vazia. Mas a resposta do GeekSilva funcionou bem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é possível fazer iteração em Object. Tentando fazer isso em JS você vai receber o erro `Uncaught TypeError: a is not iterable`.

No seu caso aí o que poderia resolver era ter um array de keys e fazer a iteração sobre esse array.

Seria então:

```js
// Dict
let categorias = {
  "Pediatra": ["Igor", "Luiz", "Ricardo"],
  "Ortopedista ": ["João", "Lucas", "Julia"]
};

// keys list
let categoryKeys = Object.keys(categorias);
```

Aí no HTML cê poderia fazer

```html
<optgroup *ngFor="let categoria of categoryKeys" [label]="categoria">
    <option *ngFor="let valor of categorias[categoria]" >{{ valor }}</option>
</optgroup>
```

Assim no primero ***ngFor** você tem o loop no array `['Pediatra', 'Ortopedista']` e no segundo você faz com base na categoria porque está passando a **key** para o dicionário.